# Find axis of rotation for matrix BA given matrix AB

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ and $B$ be in $SO(3)$. 
Then $AB$ and $BA$ are also in $SO(3)$

So let AB be a rotation around some vector $\hat{w}$ at some angle $\theta$, represented $AB = R(\hat{w},\theta)$.

Find the axis and angle of rotation s.t. $BA=R(\hat{u},\phi)$

My thoughts so far:

Since trace(AB) = trace(BA) clearly $\theta = \phi$.

We know that 
$$ABx=(cos\theta)x+(1-cos\theta)(\hat{w}\bullet x)\hat{w}+(sin\theta) \hat{w}\times x$$

and multiplying by B gets:

$$(BA)Bx=(cos\theta)(Bx)+B(1-cos\theta)(\hat{w}\bullet x)\hat{w}+B(sin\theta)\hat{w}\times x$$

to try to find the result where BA is multiplied by the vector Bx, but I can't see where to go from here. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If $AB=I_3$, then $BA=I_3$. Now $AB\not= I_3,BA\not= I_3$ and $AB=Rot(u,\theta)$. $AB$ and $BA=Rot(v,\phi)$ are similar matrices; then $\theta=\pm \phi$. It remains to find $v$ up to signum. $ABu=u$ implies that $(BA)(Bu)=Bu$ and $Bu=\pm v$. We choose $v=Bu$ and, consequently, $BA=Rot(Bu,\theta)$; indeed, if $||v||=1,<u,v>=0$, then

EDIT. $\sin(\theta)=<ABv,u\times v>=\det(ABv,u,v)$ and $\sin(\phi)=<BA(Bv),Bu\times Bv>=\det(BABv,Bu,Bv)$. Since $B$ is a rotation, $\sin(\theta)=\sin(\phi)$ and $\theta=\phi$.